# Why do we define quotient groups for normal subgroups only?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $G \in \mathbf{Grp}$, $H \leq G$, $G/H := \lbrace gH: g \in G \rbrace$. We can then introduce group operation on $G/H$ as $(xH)*(yH) := (x*y)H$, so that $G/H$ becomes a quotient group when $H$ is a normal subgroup.

But why do we only work with quotient groups by normal subgroups? If we introduce the notion of *left quotient group* in the above manner, how much good properties of a quotient group do we lose?

Comment: That operation on cosets is well-defined if and only if H is a normal subgroup.  If H is just a subgroup, what you call "left quotient group" has the more standard name "set with a left group action". More precisely, the coset spaces G/H describe essentially all the examples of sets with transitive left G-actions. It is part of the general theory of groups acting on sets.

Comment: What do you mean by well-defined? It is a group, which is trivial to show.

Comment: To define the group operation, you have to fix coset representatives. You need to check that the coset you get as a result of the group operation is independent of the coset representatives you chose. But that is only true if the subgroup is normal. So before you "trivially show" that your operation gives a group, you should check that you have a well-defined operation on cosets in the first place.

Comment: Do you mean that if $xH = zH$ then it is necessary for $H$ to be a normal subgroup in order for the equality $(xy)H = (zy)H$ to hold for all $y \in G$?

Comment: Yes (as is easily checked).

Comment: An alternative definition of normal subgroup might of interest. The algebra book of your choice would probably contain a proposition that says "kernels of homormorphisms are precisely normal subgroups". That might help you.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1014784/589

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I cannot comment yet, but I thought I would elaborate on what is meant by being well-defined.

In your definition of the multiplication in $G/H$, you take cosets $xH$ and $yH$ and multiply by setting their product equal to $(xy)H$. But this means that you have chosen $x$ and $y$, and there will in general be other choices of $x$ and $y$ that give the same cosets. So if you have $xH$ = $x'H$ and $yH$ = $y'H$, you want to be sure that you also have $(xy)H = (x'y')H$, and it can be shown that this holds for all elements of $G$ iff $H$ is normal in $G$, so this is the only case where this multiplication is well-defined.

Answer (score 175):

**Added.** So, what is the problem? Let's look at the simplest example of a non-normal subgroup. Take $G=S_3$, and $H=\{e,(1,2)\}$. If we compose permutations right to left, the left cosets of $H$ in $G$ are:
\begin{align*}
eH = (1,2)H &= \{ e, (1,2)\};\\
(1,2,3)H = (1,3)H &= \{(1,2,3), (1,3)\};\\
(1,3,2)H = (2,3)H &= \{(1,3,2), (2,3)\}.
\end{align*}
If we try multiplying cosets term-by-term, we run into problems. Multiplying by $eH$ is not a problem, but take $(1,2,3)H$ multiplied by itself. The products are:
$$\{ (1,2,3)(1,2,3), (1,2,3)(1,3), (1,3)(1,2,3), (1,3)(1,3)\} = \{(1,3,2), (2,3), (1,2), e\}$$
which is not a coset. If we multiply using representatives, as in the original question,we also run into problems: if we multiply $(1,2,3)H\cdot(1,3,2)H$ as $(1,2,3)(1,3,2)H$, we get $eH$. But $(1,2,3)H = (1,3)H$, and $(1,3,2)H = (2,3)H$, and if we multiply them by looking at these alternative representatives/names, we get $(1,3)H\cdot (2,3)H = (1,3)(2,3)H = (1,3,2)H\neq eH$. That is, the multiplication rule depends on the *name* we give the coset, rather than on what the coset *is*. This means that the rule is not well-defined.

We can let $G$ act on the set of left cosets of $H$, by $g(xH) = gxH$; this is not a group, but a group action. We can also, separately, put group structures on the set of cosets of $H$ in $G$, since it will be a set, and every nonempty set can be given a group structure (assuming the Axiom of Choice; in fact, equivalent to the Axiom of Choice). But that structure will generally have nothing to do with the operation in $G$.

If we want an operation on the set of cosets, and have the operation in the cosets to be induced by the operation in $G$, then we have:

**THEOREM.** *Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup. Let $G/H = \{ gH\mid g\in G\}$ be the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$. The operation
$$\cdot \colon G/H \times G/H \to G/H\qquad\text{defined by}\qquad (xH)\cdot(yH) = (xy)H$$
is **well defined** (that is, if $xH = x'H$ and $yH=y'H$ then $xyH = x'y'H$) if and only if $H$ is normal in $G$.*

*Proof.* Suppose $H$ is normal. Then $gH=Hg$ for every $g\in G$. If $xH=x'H$ and $yH=y'H$, then 
$$xyH = x(yH) = x(Hy) = x(Hy') = (xH)y' = (x'H)y' = x'(Hy') = x'(y'H) = x'y'H$$
so the operation is well defined.

Conversely, suppose the operation is well defined so that whenever $xH=x'H$ and $yH=y'H$, then $xyH = x'y'H$. We want to show that $g^{-1}Hg\subseteq H$ for all $g\in G$. For each $h\in H$, since $hH = eH$, we have $eHgH = egH=gH$ is equal to $hHgH = hgH$. So $gH = hgH$, hence $H=g^{-1}hgH$, so $g^{-1}hg\in H$ for each $h\in H$. Thus, $g^{-1}Hg\subseteq H$. This holds for any $g\in G$, so $g^{-1}Hg\subseteq H$ for all $g\in G$, hence $H\triangleleft G$, as claimed. **QED**

And now I'm going to hijack your question a bit and go on a long excursion to a closely related subject which is not necessary to answer your question, but which I think is interesting. (Sorry!)

This is really connected to the notion of a *congruence* on an algebra (in the sense of universal algebra). A subgroup $H$ defines an equivalence relation on $G$ by $x\sim y$ if and only if $xH = yH$ (it also defines the equivalence relation of right congruence, but ignore that for now). Being an equivalence relation, it corresponds to a subset $\Phi$ of $G\times G$, with $(x,y)\in\Phi$ if and only if $x\sim y$, if and only if $xH=yH$.

But $G\times G$ also has a natural group structure inherited from $G$. Since $\Phi$ is a subset of the group $G\times G$, it makes sense to ask whether $\Phi$ is a subgroup of $G\times G$ or not.

**THEOREM.** *$\Phi$ is a subgroup of $G\times G$ if and only if $H$ is normal in $G$.*

*Proof.* Note that $\Phi$ always contains $(e,e)$ (in fact, the entire diagonal). Assume first that $H$ is normal. If $(x,y)\in \Phi$, then $xH=yH$. Hence, $Hx = Hy$, and taking inverses of each element we get $x^{-1}H = y^{-1}H$, so $(x^{-1},y^{-1})\in\Phi$; thus, $\Phi$ is closed under inverses. If $(x,y),(z,w)\in\Phi$, then $xH=yH$, $zH=wH$, so by what we proved above we have $xzH = ywH$, so $(xz,yw)=(x,y)(z,w)\in\Phi$. Thus, $\Phi$ is closed under products, so $\Phi$ is a subgroup of $G\times G$.

Conversely, suppose that $\Phi$ is a subgroup. If $xH=yH$ and $zH=wH$, then $(x,y),(z,w)\in \Phi$, hence $(x,y)(z,w)=(xz,yw)\in\Phi$; thus, $xzH = ywH$. This proves that the operation $xH\cdot zH \mapsto xzH$ is well-defined, so by the theorem above $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. **QED**

---

**Added.** (Stuff between the two horizontal lines was added in this edit).

Okay, how about this? Can we define *some* equivalence relation $\sim$ on a group $G$ so that we can multiply equivalence classes through representatives, have it be well-defined, but not have $\sim$ "come from" a normal subgroup?

That is: suppose $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on the group $G$ (*any* equivalence relation; all we require is that it be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive on the underlying set of $G$), and let $[x]$ denote the equivalence class of $x$ for each $x$ in $G$. We want to define a multiplication on the quotient set $G/\sim$ by $[x][y] = [xy]$. When is this well defined?

**THEOREM.** *Let $G$ be a group, and let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $G$. Then the multiplication on $G/\sim$ defined by $[x][y]=[xy]$ is well defined if and only if $\sim$ is a subgroup of $G\times G$.*

*Proof.* If $\sim$ is a subgroup of $G\times G$ and $[x]=[z]$, $[y]=[w]$, then $(x,z),(y,w)\in \sim$, so $(x,z)(y,w) = (xy,zw)\in \sim$, hence $[xy]=[zw]$, so multiplication is well defined.

Conversely, suppose the multiplication is well defined. Since $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, $(e,e)\in\sim$. Also, if $(x,z), (y,w)\in\sim$, then $[x]=[z]$, $[y]=[w]$, so $[x][y]=[xy]$ equals $[z][w]=[zw]$, so $(xy,zw)=(x,y)(z,w)\in\sim$. Thus, $\sim$ is a submonoid of $G\times G$. It only remains to show that $\sim$ is closed under inverses. Suppose that $(x,y)\in\sim$. Multiplying by $(x^{-1},x^{-1})$ on the left and $(y^{-1},y^{-1})$ on the right (both elements of $\sim$) we have $(y^{-1},x^{-1})\in\sim$. Since $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, it is reflexive, so $(x^{-1},y^{-1})\in\sim$. Thus, $\sim$ is a subgroup of $G\times G$, as claimed. **QED**

Okay, so we can define the multiplication on the quotient set if and only if the equivalence relation is a subgroup of $G\times G$. Do all such equivalence relations "come" from subgroups? Yes:

**THEOREM.** *Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $G$ that is a subgroup of $G\times G$, and let $H=\{g\in G\mid g\sim e\}$. Then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $x\sim y$ if and only if $xH=yH$.*

*Proof.* We can identify $G$ with the subgroup $G\times\{e\}$ of $G\times G$; then $H$ corresponds to the intersection of the subgroup $\sim$ and the subgroup $G\times\{e\}$, hence is a subgroup of $G$.

To see that $\sim$ is in fact left congruence modulo $H$, simply note that $xH=yH$ if and only if $y^{-1}x\in H$, if and only if $(y^{-1}x,e)\in \sim$, if and only if $(y,y)(y^{-1}x,e)\in\sim$, if and only if $(x,y)\in \sim$, if and only if $x\sim y$. That $H$ is normal now follows because multiplication of cosets (equivalently, of equivalence classes modulo $\sim$) is well defined. **QED**

---

When we generalize this to an arbitrary *algebra* (in the sense of universal algebra; examples include magmas, monoids, semigroups, groups, rings, $K$-algebras, lattices, etc), we get the notion of *congruence*:

**Definition.** Let $A$ be an *algebra* (in the sense of universal algebra). A *congruence on $A$* is an equivalence relation $\Phi$ on $A$ such that $\Phi$ is a subalgebra of $A\times A$.

**THEOREM.** *Let $A$ and $B$ be algebras of the same type, and let $f\colon A\to B$ be a homomorphism; define $\Phi_f = \{(x,y)\in A\times A\mid f(x)=f(y)\}$. Then $\Phi_f$ is a congruence on $A$. Conversely, if $\Psi$ is a congruence on $A$, then there exists an algebra $\mathcal{B}$ and a homomorphism $\pi\colon A\to \mathcal{B}$ such that $\Psi=\Phi_{\pi}$.*

*Special case.* Let me do the proof with semigroups. First, let $f\colon A\to B$ be a semigroup homomorphism; then $\Phi_f$ is an equivalence relation on $A$. To show it is a subsemigroup of $A\times A$, suppose $(x,y),(z,w)\in \Phi_f$. Then $f(xz) = f(x)f(z) = f(y)f(w) = f(yw)$, so $(xz,yw)\in\Phi_f$. Thus, $\Phi_f$ is a subsemigroup of $A\times A$, hence a congruence.

Conversely, suppose that $\Psi$ is a congruence. Let $\mathcal{B}=A/\Psi$, the set of equivalence classes of $\Psi$ in $A$. Let $[x]$ denote the class of $x$. We define a multiplication on $\mathcal{B}$ by $[a][b]=[ab]$. We must prove that this is well defined: suppose $[x]=[y]$ and $[z]=[w]$. Then $(x,y),(z,w)\in\Psi$, so $(xz,yw)\in\Psi$ (since $\Psi$ is a congruence). Therefore, $[xz]=[yw]$, so multiplication is well-defined. It is now easy to verify that multiplication is associative:
$$[x]([y][z]) = [x][yz] = [x(yz)]=[(xy)z] = [xy][z] = ([x][y])[z].$$
Thus, $\mathcal{B}$ is a semigroup. The map $\pi\colon A\to \mathcal{B}$ given by $\pi(a)=[a]$ is easily verified to be a homomorphism, and $\Phi_{\pi}=\Psi$.

The proof for an arbitrary algebra with operations $f_1,\ldots,f_k$ of arities $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ (or even an infinite number of operations, each with finite arities) is essentially the same.
**QED**

One can then prove the Isomorphism Theorems for "congruences" in exactly the analogous manner as for groups and rings, for any class of algebras.

In Groups and Rings, we can "get away" with not studying congruences because if $\Phi$ is a congruence on $G$, then we can let $N = \{ g\in G\mid (g,e)\in\Phi\}$, and it turns out that $\Phi$ is the equivalence relation induced by $N$. Essentially, a congruence tells you that certain things are equal, but in groups (and rings), instead of saying "$x$ is equal to $y$", we can say "$xy^{-1}$ is the identity". The normal subgroup (resp. the ideal) is the set of elements equivalent to the identity. In more general classes, such as semigroups, we don't have the luxury of expressing any identity in the form $w=e$, so we must actually keep track of both sides of the equality.

This is all part of *Universal Algebra*. I cannot recommend [George Bergman's book](http://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/) highly enough if you want a great introduction to the subject (with a Category Theory flavor).

Comment: Wow, you really wanted to get a point across, didn't you? :D Thumbs up!

Comment: @Alexei: Not "get a point across", but rather take the opportunity to point out a bunch of ideas that come together and happen to show that "normal subgroups" is the only game in town when you want to define "quotient groups". I happen to like the idea of congruences better than normal subgroups because they are more "natural": you just define $a\sim b \Longleftrightarrow f(a)=f(b)$; it is a bit of a historical accident that in the first two abstract structures it turns out we can "codify" the congruence with a substructure-with-something-extra (normal subgroups for groups, ideals for rings).

Comment: Yes, these are pretty interesting ideas. Thank you :)

Comment: This was an awesome answer, and your reference of Bergman's text looks great.  Thank you.

Comment: Great answer as always! I was very confused but not anymore. There is also something about your writing style. I barely looked at the first two paragraphs and I knew this answer was by you. I scrolled down immediately to check and indeed, I was correct. Thanks for the answer, have a great day! $\ddot{\smile}$

Comment: Wow, the theorem in the end is a very beautiful and general result. Though I didn't give it a lot of thought I have a question. It seems like we can get the first isomorphism theorem as a simple corollary of what you stated here. Am I right?

Comment: @heinwol depending on exactly what you mean by the "First Isomorphism Theorem." In a sense, this is the General Algebra version of Noether's first isomorphism theorem, so for groups you get it by noting groups are a special case, just like semigroups.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh, they even say it on the appropriate [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Universal_algebra).) It seems like we cannot always produce an entity like "a normal subgroup" or "an ideal" in arbitrary algebraic structure, so we need to reformulate everything in terms of congruences. Thus we get exactly the variant you proposed above. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: What if we pick a representative, in order to sidestep the "well-defined" issue entirely?

Comment: @VivaanDaga And how do you define the product? You would need that if $a$ and $b$ are representatives, then so is $ab$. And it turns out you can't do that for all cosets unless the subgroup is normal **and** has a complement. If you try to define it as "the coset that contains $ab$" then theorems apply and it only works if your subgroup is normal.

Comment: Ah, if we define it in the latter way then we can't prove we have a group because the associativity condition requires normality?

Comment: @VivaanDaga Try it with $S_3$ and $H=\{e,(12)\}$. If you pick $(13)$ and $(23)$, their product is in the class of $(13)$. So you would need the class of $(23)$ to be the identity. That means you have to pick $(12)$, not $e$, as a rep for $eH$. But then $(12)(13)$ is also in the class of $(13)$, so you don't have a group. No set of choices will work.

Comment: Ok, so we can claim that it works iff we have normality right?

Comment: @VivaanDaga it's not a "claim". It's a theorem.

Comment: Right and the only place we need normailty is in showing associativity of the defined group. (well defined ness is no longer a problem). Did I get that right?

Comment: @VivaanDaga Did you not read the example I **just** gave you? It wasn't associativity that was the problem. It was that you had  $x,y,z$ with $x\neq y$ and $xz=yz=z$. So, no. you got that wrong. You just *don't get a group*, for any of a **number** of **different** reasons.

Comment: But if you just check the group axioms with the product defined by the latter manner(from your first comment to me), only associativity seems to fail.

Comment: @VivaanDaga You aren't listening, and I'm not spending any more time commenting on an old post in the hope that you will eventually stop and actually read what I write. If all you want to do is talk and say the same thing regardless of what I reply, then don't do it where you are constantly pinging me.

Comment: As far as I can see the example you gave is for the *first* definition of product(in your first comment to me). I am asking about the *second* definition of product(in your first comment to me.)

Comment: @VivaanDaga No, the example is for the second definition, so you still aren't listening. Since you don't care what I say, I ask you again to stop commenting hers. If you want to just talk to yourself, stop involving me.

Answer (score 7):

(Sorry, new here, can't comment.)

To expand on Alex's answer, if we demand that $(xh)(yh) \in (xy)H$ for any coset representative $h$, then this is equivalent to asking that $y^{-1}hyh \in H$ for all $h \in H$. But the conjugate $y^{-1}hy$ need not lie in $H$ if $H$ isn't normal, hence the claim that the operation in your "left quotient group" isn't well defined.

Comment: $(xH)(yH) \mapsto (xy)H$ need not be generated by the group operation of $G$; sure, if you constrain yourself to such an operation you do need a normal subgroup. I probably confused you with my notation :) However, another kind of problem arises, see my response to Alex.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. See Tobais's answer. No matter how we look at the group operation, it has to be independent of which coset representatives we choose. The problem is easiest to see if you just consider the product $(xh)(yh)$ like I do above, but expand Tobais's $(xy)H=(x'y')H$ and you'll still get a term like $y^{-1}hyh$ which needs to be in $H$. Therefore $H$ must be normal.

Comment: Unfortunately, if we just think of cosets as of elements of $G/H$ your answer doesn't get the point :P

Comment: It seems like some of the confusion is coming from whether or not we can put a different group structure on the set of cosets $G/H$. Perhaps we can, but we certainly wouldn't call it the quotient group of $G$ by $H$ because it has nothing to do with $G$ or $H$ as groups.

Comment: @Sean Tilson: It is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice that every nonempty set can be given a group structure. Certainly, the set of cosets is a set, so we can give it *a* group structure (assuming AC), but which will likely have nothing to do with the operation in $G$.

Comment: That is exactly my point.

Comment: @Sean Tilson: Yes; I was addressing your "perhaps we can"; in ZFC, we *definitely* can.

Comment: Ah, i meant "perhaps" in a non-technical sense, more of a "if we really wanted to, but why would we" like it is out at the edges of reasonable thought.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on a comment made by another user in the above, if the operation $(xH)\ast(yH):=(xy)H$ is well-defined, then $(G/H,\ast)$ is a group. Hence $f:G\to G/H$ defined by $f(g)=gH$ is a homomorphism and $H=\ker f$. However, the kernel of a group homomorphism is always normal. Therefore $H$ has to be normal.

(As shown by Arturo Magidin's answer, actually $(xH)\ast(yH):=(xy)H$ is well-defined if and only if $H$ is normal.)