# Find all subrings of $\mathbb{Z}^2\,$(congruences as subalgebras of the square $\Bbb Z^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This may be a simple question:

> Find all subrings of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: Are your rings required to have an identity, and do your subrings have to have the same identity?

Answer (score 20):

The strictest interpretation of the question is the one in which rings have identities and subrings have to share identities.  Then any subring of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ contains the identity $(1, 1)$, hence the subring generated by $(1, 1)$, which is the diagonal copy $(k, k)$ of $\mathbb{Z}$.  If $R$ is a subring, then to describe any extra elements of $R$ it suffices to describe the extra elements of the form $(0, k)$ (since the existence of any particular extra element $(a, b)$ can be deduced from the existence of the extra element $(a, b) - (a, a) = (0, b-a)$.)  If there are any extra elements of the form $(0, k)$, they must form an ideal of the second copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ (since they must be closed under addition and under multiplication by the diagonal copy of $\mathbb{Z}$) hence the only choice is that the extra elements are of the form $(0, nk)$ for some fixed positive integer $n$ and all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.  These elements generate the ring $R_n$ of all pairs $(a, b)$ such that $a \equiv b \bmod n$, and these are all possible subrings (if one includes $R_{\infty}$, which corresponds to the diagonal case).

There are two other interpretations: one in which rings have to have identities but subrings don't have to share them, and one in which rings don't have to have identities.  I'll leave these as an exercise if you're interested; you should think about the subrings of $\mathbb{Z}$ first as a warm-up.

Answer (score 19):

It is instructive to highlight that the argument sketched in Qiaochu's answer is actually a special case of a general relationship between congruences and **subalgebras of the square**. Generalizing the way we define congruences for the ring of integers modulo $\rm\,m,\,$ we define a congruence $\,\equiv\,$ as an equivalence relation on an algebra $\rm A $ that is compatible with all operations on $\rm A,\,$ e.g. for rings such compatibility means that if $\rm a'\equiv a,\ b'\equiv b\,$ then $\rm\, a'+b'\,\equiv\, a+b\ $ and similarly for all other operations. Viewing the equivalence relation $\,\equiv\,$  as a subset of $\rm\ A\times A,\, $ this compatibility condition is a closure condition: $ $ if $\rm\, (a',a),\,(b',b)\in\;\equiv\,$ then $\rm\, (a'+b',a+b)\in\; \equiv\:\!,\, $ i.e. $\,\equiv\,$ is closed under addition in $\rm\, A\times A.\,$ Thus an equivalence relation on $\rm A $ is compatible with the operations of $\rm A $ iff it forms a *subalgebra* of $\rm\,A^2\,$ (subalgebra of its square).

Returning to the case as hand, where $\rm A $ is the ring $\,\mathbb Z,\, $ let $\rm\,S\,$ be a subring of $\rm\,\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\,.\, $ By the above, to show that $\rm\,S\,$ is a congruence we need only show that it is an equivalence relation. First, since *here* $\rm\ (1,1)\in S\ $ generates the *full* diagonal $\rm\, (1,1)\ \mathbb Z,\, $ we deduce that $\rm\,S\,$ is a *reflexive* relation. Second, $\rm\,S\,$ is *symmetric* since if $\rm\, (a,b)\in S\ $ then also in $\rm\,S\,$ is $\rm\ (a+b,a+b)-(a,b) = (b,a).\, $ Third,  $\rm\,S\,$ is *transitive* since if $\rm\, (a,b),\ (b,c)\in S\, $ then so too is $\rm\, (a,b)\,+\,(c,c)-(c,b) =(a,c).\, $ Finally,$\,$ for every ring $\rm\,R,\, $ a congruence $\,\equiv\,$ is uniquely determined by the congruence class of $\,0,\,$ since $\rm\ a\equiv b\iff a-b\equiv 0.\, $ But the congruence class of $\,0\,$ has the structure of an *ideal* since $\rm\ a,b\equiv 0\ \Rightarrow\ a+b\equiv 0\ $ and $\rm\ ac\equiv 0,\,$ for all $\rm\,c \in R\,$ (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/894257/242) for more on such *ideal-determined* algebras, i.e. where congruences are determined by a *single* equivalence class).

This explains - from general principles - the connection observed in Qiaochu's post between subalgebras of $\,\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\,$ and ideals of $\rm\mathbb Z.\, $ Note that  while the connections between congruences and subalgebras of the square, and congruences and ideals hold true for every ring $\rm\,R,\,$ the rest of the above argument doesn't follow since generally  $\rm\,(1,1)\,$ doesn't generate the *full* diagonal $\rm\,(1,1)\, R.\,$ Indeed, it generates only the diagonal of the characteristic subring (the image of $\,\mathbb Z\,$ in $\rm\,R)$.

The above argument shows that in order to verify that a subalgebra of $\rm\,R\times R\,$ is a ring congruence it suffices to show that the subalgebra contains the diagonal (i.e. it is reflexive), since this implies the other equivalence relation properties (symmetry and transitivity). This leads to the following

**Theorem** $\ $ The following are equivalent for a ring $\rm\,R\,$ and set $\rm\ S\subset R\times R$

$\rm(1)\quad S\ $ is a congruence on $\rm\,R\,$

$\rm(2)\quad S\ $ is a subalgebra of $\rm\,R\times R\,$ and $\rm\,S \supset (1,1)\, R$

$\rm(3)\quad I\, :=\, \{\, r\in R\, :\ (r,0)\in S \,\}\ $ is an ideal in $\rm\,R\,$

**Proof** $\rm\ (1\Rightarrow 2)\ $ follows the same way as sketched above. $\rm\ (1\!\!\iff\!\! 3)$ is well-known.
$\rm (2\Rightarrow 3)\quad i,\,j\in I\ \Rightarrow\ (i,0),\,(j,0)\in S\ \Rightarrow\ (i,0)+(j,0)=(i+j,0)\in S\ \Rightarrow\ i+j\in I $
Also $\rm\; r\in R,\, j\in I\ \Rightarrow\ (r,r),\,(j,0)\in S\ \Rightarrow\ (r,r)\, *\, (j,0) = (r *\, j, 0)\in S\ \Rightarrow\ r\, *\,j \in I$

For further details see any good textbook on universal algebra, e.g. Burris and Sankappanavar's textbook [A Course in Universal Algebra](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Esnburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra.pdf#page=154) or George Bergman's [An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions](http://www.math.berkeley.edu/%7Egbergman/245).

Comment: Also related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14282/why-do-we-define-quotient-groups-for-normal-subgroups-only/14315#14315, where I discuss it for groups.

Comment: Just to add a piece of terminology: (2) can be phrased as "$S$ is a sub-$R$-algebra of $R \times R$."

Comment: For further background see also [this post.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/42125/242)