# Associativity, commutativity and distributivity of modulo arithmetic

Tags: abstract-algebra

Textbooks usually state "*it is not hard to check that in modular arithmetic the usual associative, commutative and distributive properties continue to apply*". Is there a way other than tedious proof by case analysis? For example, perhaps it is more convincing to notice that, say Z/13, is cyclic group over addition and multiplication and, therefore, commutativity and associativity follows? What about distributivity?

Comment: Ehr... to show that it is a cyclic *group* you would have to show that it is a *group*, and in particular that the operation is associative.

Comment: FWIW, your question got linked (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14189299/are-fixed-width-integers-distributive-over-multiplication)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To prove (or "notice") that $\mathbb{Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$ is a (cyclic) group under addition you would need to know first of all that it is a group under addition; and in order to know that it is a group under addition, you would need to know that addition is associative, has an identity element, and has inverses; so you have to show it is associative. You cannot save yourself knowing/showing it is associative by first showing it's a group: showing/knowing associativity is a prerequisite of it being a group.

You don't have to prove it by "case analysis", but only through the basic properties of congruences. The key is really to show that addition and multiplication *are well defined*.

That is, we define addition and multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ by "class representatives": if $[a]$ is the modular class of $a$, and $[b]$ is the modular class of $b$, we define $[a]+[b]$ as $[a+b]$ and $[a][b]$ as $[ab]$. So long as these operations are *well-defined*, the properties will be inherited from the properties of the usual addition and multiplication of integers (just like in any ring modulo an ideal).

To show it is well-defined, you need to show that if $[a]=[x]$ and $[b]=[y]$, then $[a+b]=[x+y]$ and $[ax]=[by]$. This is a direct consequence of the properties of congruences, namely that if $a\equiv x\pmod{n}$ and $b\equiv y\pmod{n}$, then $a+b\equiv x+y\pmod{n}$ and $ab\equiv xy\pmod{n}$. Verifying these through the definition of congruence is indeed trivial: If $a-x$ and $b-y$ are multiples of $n$, then so is $(a-x)+(b-y) = (a+b)-(x+y)$; and likewise, $(a-x)b + (b-y)x = ab - xy$ is also a multiple of $n$, being a sum of multiples of $n$.

The properties of the addition and multiplication of congruence classes now follows from the same properties for integers.

**Added.** It's important to note that it is not merely the fact that we are dealing with equivalence classes that makes this work. The key is really that the operations on equivalence classes defined via representatives are **well defined**.  We have a set $S$ on which we already have a (binary) operation $*$, and an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S$. If we want to define an operation on the congruence classes $S/\sim$ by using $*$, then the natural definition is to try $[a]*[b]=[a*b]$. That is: the "product" of the classes is the class of the "product". However, this does not always work correctly: it will depend on the operation and how $\sim$ relates to the operation. In the case of groups, for example, the **only** equivalence relations for which this definition works are the equivalence relations induced by normal subgroups (see [my answer to this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14282/why-do-we-define-quotient-groups-for-normal-subgroups-only/14315#14315) for an ample discussion of trying to define an operation on equivalence classes in a group).

So it is not the fact that we have an equivalence relation/partition, but really *how* the partition behaves relative to the operation.

What we have is the following general result from Universal Algebra:

**Theorem.** Let $S$ be a set, and let $*$ be an $n$-ary operation on $S$. If $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $S$, then the operation on $S/\sim$ defined by
$$*([s_1],\ldots,[s_n]) = [*(s_1,\ldots,s_n)]$$
is well-defined if and only if $\sim$ is closed under $*\times*$ as a subset of $S\times S$, where 
$$*\times*\Bigl((a_1,b_1),\ldots,(a_n,b_n)\Bigr) = \Bigl(*(a_1,\ldots,a_n),*(b_1,\ldots,b_n)\Bigr).$$

*Proof.* Suppose $*$ is well defined. If $(a_1,b_1),\ldots,(a_n,b_n)\in \sim$, then $[a_i]=[b_i]$, so by assumption we have that 
$$[*(a_1,\ldots,a_n)] = *([a_1],\ldots,[a_n]) = *([b_1],\ldots,[b_n])=[*(b_1,\ldots,b_n)].$$
Therefore, 
$$*\times *\Bigl( (a_1,b_1),\ldots,(a_n,b_n)\Bigr) = \bigl( *(a_1,\ldots,a_n),*(b_1,\ldots,b_n)\bigr)\in \sim,$$
so $\sim$ is closed under $*\times *$.

Conversely, suppose that $\sim$ is closed under $*\times *$, and that $[a_1]=[b_1],\ldots,[a_n]=[b_n]$. We need to show that $*([a_1],\ldots,[a_n]) = *([b_1],\ldots,[b_n])$. Since $(a_1,b_1),\ldots,(a_n,b_n)\in \sim$, then 
$$*\times *\Bigl( (a_1,b_1),\ldots,(a_n,b_n)\Bigr) = \Bigl(*(a_1,\ldots,a_n),*(b_1,\ldots,b_n)\Bigr)\in \sim,$$
hence $[*(a_1,\ldots,a_n)] = [*(b_1,\ldots,b_n)]$. But this is exactly what we need to show $*$ is well defined on $S/\sim$. **QED**

So *if* the equivalence relation is a substructure of $S\times S$, *then* we can define the induced operation on $S/\sim$ via representatives, and this operation on $S/\sim$ will inherit the properties of the operation from $S$.

Thus, to show that sums and products of congruence classes modulo $m$ in the integers inherit the properties of the sum and product of integers is equivalent to showing that the equivalence relation "congruent modulo $m$", $\equiv_m$, interpreted as a subset of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ (the latter with coordinate-wise operations). This is *precisely* showing that if $a\equiv x\pmod{m}$ (i.e., $(a,x)\in\equiv_m$) and $b\equiv y\pmod{m}$ (i.e., $(b,y)\in\equiv_m$) , then $a+b\equiv x+y\pmod{m}$ (i.e., $(a,x)+(b,y)=(a+b,x+y)\in\equiv_m$) and $ab\equiv xy\pmod{m}$ (i.e., $(a,x)(b,y) = (ab,xy)\in\equiv_m$). So it still comes down to the *specific* properties of the equivalence relation, and not merely to the fact that it *is* an equivalence relation.

Comment: Once again, I was typing up an answer when a better one came in from you.  It seems there is some advantage to being a professional teacher.

Comment: Thanks Arturo. Now that congruence classes are defined via equivalence relation, perhaps you can recast your answer in terms of equivalence relation properties? Do idempotence, symmetry and transitiveness somehow imply "well definess" of the equivalence class?

Comment: @Tegiri: It is not *merely* the fact that they are equivalence classes that makes things well defined. See my answer in the thread asking why group quotients are defined only modulo normal subgroups for a discussion of why you need more than just an equivalence relation: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14282/why-do-we-define-quotient-groups-for-normal-subgroups-only/14315#14315

Comment: Well, perhaps it could even better be explained if we talk about relations exclusively -- for one thing it's a little bit awkward to mix relations and functions... For example, let P be a partial order and S be an equivalence relation. Then, partial order P is well-defined (with respect to S) when ... A relation can be viewed as a function of course; I'm simply looking for the simplest intuition for the concept of congruence.

Comment: @Tegiri: I disagree: there is a very natural way to extend an operation on $S$ to $S\times S$; there isn't such a natural way to extend a *relation* on $S$ to a relation on $S\times S$ (for example, how do you extend the total order of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$? Lexicographically, anti-lexicographically? If you try $(a,x)\preceq(b,y)\Leftrightarrow a\leq b\lor x\leq y$, you don't get an order, and if you try $(a,x)\preceq(b,y)\Leftrightarrow a\leq b\land x\leq y$, you don't get a total order like you had before. Once you have an operation on $S\times S$ and a subset, (cont)

Comment: @Tegiri: (cont), checking whether the subset is closed under the operation is in fact very natural, nothing awkward about it. We don't have a relation on $S\times S$, after all, we have a *subset*.

Comment: How about this: x~x' & x<y & y~y' <-> x'<y'? Thus, congruence in relational terms is just commutativity of relational composition "~< = <~"?     Regarding, your doubt about order, sure we can do it for lattices, at least?

Comment: @Tegiri: Lattices are actually algebras: you have the join and meet *operations* (the lattice order is derived from the operations; or the other way around), so lattices fall within the general frame of algebras and operations, no problems there. Relations are just hard to deal with (universal algebra can even manage partial operations with relative ease, but relations are just hard). The beauty of the theorem above is that it is simple, and involves checking natural conditions. For relations, I cannot come up with anything better than simply state "it must be compatible" (cont)

Comment: @Tegir (cont). For instance, if you want to define $[a]R[b]\Leftrightarrow aRb$, you ask that "if $x\sim a$ and $y\sim b$ and $aRb$, then $xRy$". It puts too many restrictions, too: if $R$ is reflexive (what you call "idempotent") then a necessary (but not sufficient) condition would be for $\sim$ to be contained in $R$.

Comment: Note: for more on the equivalence between congruences and subalgebras of the square containing the diagonal see [my post here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16121/find-all-subrings-of-mathbbz2/16157#16157)

Comment: @Arturo: Yes, I have meant that if one can define congruence operationally for lattices, then we can see what congruence may be for induced order. Here is congruence relation on min&max algebra [Integers;min,max]: x≡y mod[ak+b,ak+a+b) <-> ∃k ak+b ≤ x ≤ ak+a+b & ak+b ≤ y ≤ ak+a+b  defines equivalent classes that are well defined with respect to min and max... (BTW, can it be defined in terms of equality, like standard congruence x≡y (mod N) <-> ∃k x=y+kN ?) I see that the topic of congruence warrants a dedicated question.

Comment: @Tegiri: Again, lattices are special within the class of partially ordered sets, because lattices are "really" algebras, so they fall under the aegis of the general set-up for operations. For *some* kinds of lattices, there is a correspondence between congruence relations (equivalence relations that are sublattices of $L\times L$) and *ideals* of $L$ (an ideal of a lattice $L$ is a nonempty subset $I$ which contains a join if and only if it is closed under joins, and if $c\leq a$ and $a\in I$, then $c\in I$). But I believe this does not hold for all latices.

Comment: @Tegiri: What you propose is not an equivalence relation (you need one of the inequalities strict). Consider $a=2$, $b=0$. Then under your definition $0\equiv 2$, $2\equiv 4$, but $0\not\equiv 4$, so it is not transitive. You should change the condition to $ak+b\leq x\lt a(k+1)b$ and $ak+b\leq y\lt a(k+1)b$.

Comment: @Tegiri: for your example (suitably corrected), there isn't a subset $N$ that works if $a\gt 1$. Since $b$ and $b+1$ are congruent, you need $b+1\in b+kN$, so either $1$ or $-1$ must be in $N$. But then all elements are congruent, since given any $x$ and $y$, taking $k = y-x$ or $x-y$ (depending on whether $-1$ or $1$ is in $N$) you have $x\in y+kN$.  So no such $N$ exists.

Comment: @Tegiri: In any case, sums would be the wrong way to try to define it. You are in a lattice, so your equivalence classes should be defined in terms of meets or joins, not sums. So it would make more sense to ask if there is an $N$ such that $x\equiv y\Leftrightarrow x\in y\land N$ (or $x\in y\lor N$). But again the answer is "no". Since $b\equiv b+1$, you would need $b\in b+1\land N$, so $b\in N$. But then $b\equiv n$ for all $n\geq b$, since $b\in b\land N$. If you use $\lor$, then the same argument shows $b+1\equiv m$ for all $m\leq b+1$.

Comment: @Arturo: yes I have meant semiopen intervals, but it was copy-and-paste typo. Partitioning Z (or Q or R, for that matter) into a union of disjoint semiopen intervals (not necessarily regularly spaced!) is arguably more intuitive than Z/nZ. I don't follow your argument that such partitioning won't respect min and max.

Comment: @Tegiri: I did **not** claim the partitioning won't respect min and max. What I said is that you cannot define it "in terms of equality, like standard congruence". That is, there does not exist an $N$ such that $x$ and $y$ are in the same partition if and only if $x=y+kN$ for some $k$. I never touched on max and min. As for "arguably more intuitive", I will simply say that it is now a theorem that your intuition and mine are linearly disjoint...

Answer (score 4):

That ring axioms are preserved in congruence rings is simply a *derived* consequence of the fact that the map to the congruence class $\rm\ n\to [n]\ $ is a *homomorphism*, i.e. it preserves all the fundamental operations of the structure. Thus it necessarily preserves expressions *composed* of these operations, and hence it preserves all identities (laws) expressed in terms of these operations. For example, let's explicitly derive the preservation of the distributive law in a congruence ring:

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad [a(b+c)]\ =\ [a][b+c]\ =\ [a]([b]+[c])$

$\rm\quad\quad\quad\quad [ab+ac]\ =\ [ab]+[ac]\ =\ [a][b]+ [a][c]$

Hence $\rm\ [a]([b]+[c])\ =\ [a][b]+[a][c]\ $ i.e. the distributive law holds too in the congruence ring. Precisely the same proof works also for all the other ring laws, e.g. associative, commutative, etc. One is simply lifting a preservation property from the generating operations to expressions composed of those fundamental generating operations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pedestrian strategy designed to avoid abstract algebra and equivalence relations, to understand why Z_n satisfies the ring axioms.

Fix a modulus n at least 1. For each whole number x define the REMAINDER mod n as R(x)=r with the r the smallest nonnegative solution to the equation x-qn=r.

A) Show that R(x+y)=R(R(x)+R(y)) for whole numbers x and y

B) Show that R(xy)=R(R(x)R(y)) for whole numbers x and y

C) Use A) to prove that R((x+y)+z)=R(x+(y+z)) for whole numbers x,y,z

D) Use B) to prove that R((xy)z)=R(x(yz)) for whole numbers x,y,z

E) Show that R(R(xy)+R(xz))=R(R(x)R(y+z)), by repeated application of A) and B), for whole numbers x,y, and z.

Define Z_n={0,1,2,3...,n-1} , to combine two numbers add/multiply in the usual way, then take the remainder. A-E imply associativity and distributivity. 0 and 1 are identities, and n-x is the additive inverse of x.