# Near-rings: why are ideals defined like that?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

While I am learning the very basics of Near-rings ,I have come across the following statement: 
   " a subgroup I of N is an ideal  iff  $$n \equiv m \pmod I$$ and $$x \equiv y \pmod I$$ 
implies  $$n+x \equiv m+y \pmod I$$  and $$n.x \equiv m.y \pmod I$$

Here, ($N$,+,.) a near-ring, $n,m,x,y$ are elements in $N$.
 Can anyone  explain me the whole idea of these congruences?
One more thing I need to know is "Do these elements belong to the ideal just like in case of the rings?"

Answer (score 2):

Though not familiar with near-rings I will try to answer.

**Congruences**
can be described as *equivalence relations* on structures like groups,
semigroups, monoids, rings et cetera, *that respect these structures*.
For instance if $C$ denotes a congruence on semigroup $S$ then $aCa'\wedge bCb'$
implies that $abCa'b'$. This is what I mean by respecting the structure. A quotient is then induced as a new semigroup.
Elements are equivalence classes and the original structure on $S$
gives rise to a sortlike structure on the quotient. In many cases
there is a special equivalence class that is determining in the sense that there is a one-to-one relation between the congruences and these special equivalence classes. 
The focus is then very much on these - somehow congruence representing - classes (normal subgroups in groups,
ideals in rings). The word *ideal* is used in your question which is
a strong indication that this will also be the case for near- rings. The conditions that you mention in your question then tell us that the equivalence relation indeed *respects* the structure of the near-ring.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/42125/242) for further discussion of algebraic structures whose congruences are determined by a single congruence class (including literature references).