# Proving that $12^n + 2(5^{n-1})$ is a multiple of 7 for $n\geq 1$ by induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

> Prove by induction that $12^n + 2(5^{n-1})$ is a multiple of $7$.

Here's where I am right now:

Assume $n= k $ is correct:
$$12^k+2(5^{k-1}) = 7k.$$

Let $n= k+1 $:
$$12^{k+1} + 2(5^k)$$
$$12^k(12) + 2(5^k)$$

Any ideas on how I can proceed from here?

Comment: are you sure that you have made no typo?

Comment: I think you plugged $k+1$ in wrong.  You should get $12^{k+1}+2(5^{k+1}-1)$.

Comment: Without induction: $12^n+2(5^{n-1})\equiv 5^n+2(5^{n-1})\equiv 7(5^{n-1})\equiv 0\pmod{7}$.

Comment: @user31415 It *does* use induction but the induction is hidden in a lemma, that $\,12\equiv 5\,\Rightarrow\, 12^k\equiv 5^k,\,$ the [Congruence Power Rule.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

Answer (score 1):

**Basis Step:**

$P(1) = 12^1 + 2\cdot5^{1-1} = 12 + 2 = 14 = 7\cdot 2$

Thus $P(1)$ is true.

**Inductive Step:**

Assume $P(k)$ holds for an arbitrary positive integer $k$. Under this assumption, let us prove that $P(k+1)$ is true, namely that

$$12^{k+1} + 2\cdot5^{k}  $$ is also a multiple of 7.

\begin{align}
12^{k+1}+2\cdot 5^k
&=12\cdot 12^k+2\cdot 5^k\\
&=12\cdot(7q-2\cdot 5^{k-1})+2\cdot 5^k\\
&=7\cdot12q-24\cdot5^{k-1}+10\cdot5^{k-1}\\
&=7\cdot12q+(-24+10)\cdot5^{k-1}\\
&=7\cdot12q+(-14)\cdot5^{k-1}\\
&=7\cdot12q+(7\cdot(-2))\cdot5^{k-1}\\
\end{align}

$7\cdot12q$ is a multiple of 7. Furthermore, $7\cdot(-2))\cdot5^{k-1}$ is a multiple of 7, thus their sum is a multiple of 7, illustrated by the right hand side of the equation.

The last line shows that $P(k+1)$ is true under the assumption that $P(k)$ is true. This completes the inductive step.

Thus by the **Principal of Mathematical Induction**, the initial proposition is true for all positive integers n. This completes the proof.

Comment: The proof arises essentially by applying the Congruence Product Rule - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ *Intuitively* the induction step arises by applying the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

$$ \begin{align}{\rm mod}\,\ 7\!:\qquad \color{#0a0}{12}\  \equiv&\,\  \color{#c00} 5\\ 12^n\equiv&\,\ 5^{n-1}(-2)\qquad\  {\rm i.e.}\ \  P(n)\\\overset{\rm multiply}\Rightarrow\ \ \color{#0a0}{12}\cdot 12^n\equiv&\,\ \color{#c00}5\cdot 5^{n-1}(-2)\quad {\rm i.e.}\ \ P(n\!+\!1)\end{align}\ \qquad $$

**Remark** $\ $ If we eliminate the language of congruences by substituting inline the linked proof of the Congruence Product Rule then we obtain *precisely* the common proof in most other answers. I wrote the congruence proof in this form (vs. the more [common way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275480/proving-that-12n-25n-1-is-a-multiple-of-7-for-n-geq-1-by-induction/1275622#comment2590150_1275480))  to highlight this relationship.

Thus the inductive step need not be pulled out of a hat like magic. Rather, it has very intuitive arithmetical content as congruence multiplication. See also  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179019/prove-with-induction-that-11-divides-102n-1-for-all-natural-numbers/1179145#1179145) where I elaborate on this viewpoint (it shows in gory detail precisely how the inductive proof is equivalent to eliminating congruence language by substituting inline the proof of the Congruence Product Rule).

If we exploit to the hilt the congruence viewpoint then applying CPR we can substitute $\, -2\equiv 5\,$ reducing the proof to $\,12\equiv 5\,\Rightarrow\, 12^n\equiv 5^n,\,$ a special case of the [Congruence power Rule.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) This is a prototypical example of the great simplification afforded by the use of congruences in induction problems of this arithmetical type. Often they allow one to reduce the induction to a trivial induction,, e.g.  $\,(-1)^{2n}\equiv 1\,$ or $\,1^n\equiv 1,\,$ e.g. the above as $\,12^n/5^n\equiv (12/5)^n\equiv 1^n \equiv 1.$

Generally, unlike above, there is no need to massage the congruence proof into some form to highlight its relationship with another proof. In that case we can simply apply the congruence rules (laws) in whatever manner proves convenient (this is what was done in the linked common congruence proof, where no explicit mention was made when invoking both the congruence laws and the trivial induction conveniently encapsulated in the power law $\,12\equiv 5\,\Rightarrow\,12^n\equiv 5^n).$

Answer (score 0):

For $n=k$, we have
$$12^k+2\cdot 5^{k-1} = 7M$$
Multiplying by $12$ throughout, we obtain
$$12^{k+1}+24\cdot 5^{k-1} = 84M \implies 12^{k+1} + (2\cdot 5 + 14)\cdot 5^{k-1} = 84 M$$
which in-turn implies
$$12^{k+1} + 2\cdot 5^k +14\cdot5^{k-1} = 84M \implies 12^{k+1}+2\cdot 5^k = 14\left(6M-5^{k-1}\right)$$
Hence, the statement is true for $n=k+1$.

---

We have
$$12^n = (7+5)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \dbinom{n}k 7^k \cdot 5^{n-k} = 5^n + 7 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dbinom{n}k 7^{k-1} \cdot 5^{n-k}$$
This gives us
\begin{align}
12^n + 2 \cdot 5^{n-1} & = 2\cdot 5^{n-1} + 5^n + 7 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dbinom{n}k 7^{k-1} \cdot 5^{n-k}\\
& = \left(2+5\right)\cdot 5^{n-1} + 7 \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dbinom{n}k 7^{k-1} \cdot 5^{n-k}\\
& = 7 \cdot \left(5^{n-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \dbinom{n}k 7^{k-1} \cdot 5^{n-k}\right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Base step (you didn't mention it): for $n=1$ we have $12^1+2(5^{1-1})=14=7\cdot 2$.

Continuation to your proof:

$12^k(12)+2(5^k)=\underbrace{5(12^k+2(5^{k-1}))}_{\text{inductive hypothesis}}+\underbrace{12^k(7)}_{\text{obvious}}$

Comment: The proof arises essentially by applying the Congruence Product Rule - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should write $12^k+2\cdot 5^{k-1}=7r$ (using $k$ with two different meanings is wrong).

Then you have $12^k=7r-2\cdot 5^{k-1}$; now
\begin{align}
12^{k+1}+2\cdot 5^k
&=12\cdot 12^k+2\cdot 5^k\\
&=12\cdot(7r-2\cdot 5^{k-1})+2\cdot 5^k\\
&=7\cdot12r-24\cdot5^{k-1}+10\cdot5^{k-1}
\end{align}
and you should be able to conclude.

Remember to check the basis of the induction, that is, the case $n=1$.

---

Using congruences it is easier, of course: just observe that $12\equiv 5\pmod{7}$, so
$$
12^n+2\cdot 5^{n-1}\equiv 5^n+2\cdot 5^{n-1}\equiv 5^{n-1}(5+2)\equiv 5^{n-1}\cdot7\equiv0\pmod{7}
$$

Comment: The proof arises essentially by applying the Congruence Product Rule - see my answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque I don't want to be polemic, but I firmly believe that teaching mathematics with constant reference to “rules” is the worst way. I know *well* how this exercise can be carried out with congruences.

Comment: Focusing on syntactic trivia like names completely misses the point. The "rule" in the name is simply tradition. Nowadays we'd call it a law or axiom. Surely you don't think that teaching math with laws or axioms is the worst way. In any case, the point is that the proof has very intuitive arithmetical essence that comes to the fore when rewritten in  *equivalent* congruence form. Moreover, this technique is widely applicable.

Comment: @BillDubuque I added a proof with congruences, which is *much* straightforward than yours. And yes, I am sure that using congruences is better. Not with your convoluted technique.

Comment: It seems you still miss the point. The reason I wrote it that way was to make it easier to see how the standard inductive proof is a special case of the product rule. If you follow the link I gave tt will be clear And the above congruence proof was already mention long ago in a comment on the question.

Comment: @BillDubuque I followed the link, which shows precisely the way I don't like mathematics is taught. Personal opinion, of course, but backed up by  25 year teaching at university.

Comment: I have no clue what you don't like about congruences. They are quite useful pedagogically before students learn about quotient rings. And even later they are essential if one works in non-[ideal determined varieties,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/42125/242) i.e. where congruences are not determined by a single congruence class. And my teaching experience is also backed up by a few decades of university and online teaching.

Comment: You don't want to understand: I've nothing against congruences. But the question was about proving the assert ***by induction***, so the answer should ***first*** deal with the question and then, maybe, show alternative ways. I have much against *your* way to deal with congruences, but it's another matter.

Comment: The congruence based approach still uses induction. If you can ever find the time to express more clearly what you don't like then I am sincerely interested in reading it. I have no clue what that might be from the extremely vague things you wrote above

Answer (score 0):

For $n=k$ you have (note the use of variable $m$) 
$$12^k+2(5^{k-1})=7m\text{, where }m\in\Bbb{N}$$
For $n=k+1$ you have
$$\begin{align}12^{k+1}+2(5^k)&=(7+5)12^k+2\cdot5(5^{k-1})\\&=7\cdot12^k+5(12^k+2(5^{k-1}))\\&=7(12^k)+35m\\&=7(12^k+5m)\\&=7S\text{ ,where }S\in\Bbb{N}\end{align}$$

Comment: @hkmather802 : Thanks for improving the answer.

Comment: The proof arises essentially by applying the Congruence Product Rule - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A proof by induction has the following steps:

(1) Show that the statement is true for $n = 1$

(2) Assume that the statement is true for $n = k$, then show that it is true for $n = k + 1$.

(3) Conclude that it is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Try carrying out (1) first.

Then for (2), the key is to start with the statement for $n = k + 1$ and try make it look like the statement for $n = k$ plus something else, and then assume that it is divisible by 7 for n = k, and show that this "something else" is also divisible by 7.

In other words, for (2), start with

$12^{k+1}+2(5^{k-1+1}) = 12 \cdot 12^{k}+2(5 \cdot 5^{k-1}) = ...$

Comment: The proof arises essentially by applying the Congruence Product Rule - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof with an emphasis on clarity if you so desire:

For $n\geq 1$, let $S(n)$ denote the statement
$$
S(n) : 7\mid(12^n+2(5^{n-1}))\Longleftrightarrow 12^n+2(5^{n-1})=7m, m\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
**Base case ($n=1$):** $S(1)$ says that $7\mid(12^1+2(5^0))$, and this is true.

**Inductive step:** Fix some $k\geq 1$ and assume that $S(k)$ is true where
$$
S(k) : 7\mid(12^k+2(5^{k-1}))\Longleftrightarrow 12^k+2(5^{k-1})=7\ell, \ell\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
To be proved is that $S(k+1)$ follows where
$$
S(k+1) : 7\mid(12^{k+1}+2(5^{k}))\Longleftrightarrow 12^{k+1}+2(5^{k})=7\eta, \eta\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Beginning with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
12^{k+1} + 2(5^k) &= 12\cdot 12^k +2(5^k)\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&= 12(7\ell-2(5^{k-1}))+2(5^k)\tag{by $S(k)$, the ind. hyp.}\\[0.5em]
&= 12\cdot 7\ell-24(5^{k-1})+2(5^k)\tag{expand}\\[0.5em]
&= 12\cdot 7\ell -24(5^{k-1})+10(5^{k-1})\tag{manipulate}\\[0.5em]
&= 12\cdot 7\ell-14(5^{k-1})\tag{group like terms}\\[0.5em]
&= 7(12\ell-2(5^{k-1}))\tag{factor out a $7$}\\[0.5em]
&= 7\eta,\tag{$\eta=12\ell-2(5^{k-1}); \eta\in\mathbb{Z}$}
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$, completing the inductive step.

Thus, by mathematical induction, the statement $S(n)$ is true for all $n\geq 1$. $\blacksquare$