# How to prove that $2^{n+2}+3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by 7 using induction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

I want to prove that $2^{n+2}+3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by 7 using induction. My first step is replace $n$ with $1$.

1. $2^{1+2}+3^{2(1)+1}$
2. $2^3+3^3$
3. $8+27$
4. $35 = 7\times 5$

The next step is assume that $2^{n+2}+3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by 7. And the last step is to prove that $2^{(n+1)+2}+3^{2(n+1)+1}$.

1. $2^{(n+1)+2}+3^{2(n+1)+1}$
2. $2^{n+3}+3^{2n+3}$
3. *I got stuck here.*

How can I prove it using induction?

Comment: Hint: $2*2^{n+2} = 2^{n+3}$ and $9*3^{2n+1}= 3^{2n+3}$

Comment: Without explicit induction: $2^{n+2}+3^{2n+1}\equiv 4\cdot 2^n + 3\cdot 9^n\equiv 4\cdot 2^n+3\cdot 2^n\equiv 7\cdot 2^n\equiv 0\pmod{\! 7}$.

Comment: See also:
[Prove $3^{2n+1} + 2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $n\ge0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/233937)
[Show that $7\mid(3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2})$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/810063),
[Find all $n$ such that $3^{2n+1}+2^{n+2}$ is divisible by $7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1604280),
[Prove by induction: $2^{n+2} +3^{2n+1}$ is divisible by $7$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2427747),
[Prove that $3^{2n-1} + 2^{n+1}$ is always a multiple of $7$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2681223).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$2^{(n+1)+2}+3^{2(n+1)+1}=2(2^{n+2}+3^{2n+1})+7(3^{2n+1})$

Answer (score 2):

*Intuitively* $ $ the induction step arises by applying the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) (see below)

$$ \begin{align}{\rm mod}\,\ 7\!:\qquad \color{#0a0}{3^2}\  \equiv&\,\ \  \color{#0a0}{2}\\[2pt] 
3^{1+2n}\equiv&\,\ {-}2^{2+n}\qquad\  {\rm i.e.}\ \  P(n)\\[-4pt]
\overset{\rm multiply}\Rightarrow\ \ 3^{1+2n}\,\color{#0a0}{3^2} \equiv&\,\ {-}2^{2+n}\, \color{#0a0}{2}\\[2pt] 
{\rm i.e.}\quad\, \ 3^{1+2(\color{#c00}{n+1})}\equiv&\,\ {-}2^{2+(\color{#c00}{n+1})}\ \ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ P(\color{#c00}{n\!+\!1})\end{align}\ \qquad $$

If we eliminate the language of congruences by substituting inline the below proof of the Congruence Product Rule then we obtain *exactly* the [common proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1286528/242) given in most other answers. Even if congruences are unfamiliar, we can still impose this intuitive arithmetical structure by using the Product Rule in an equivalent *divisbility form,* namely

$$\begin{align} {\rm mod}\,\ m\!:\, A\equiv a,\, B\equiv b&\ \ \,\Longrightarrow\,\ \ AB\equiv ab\qquad\text{Congruence Product Rule}\\[3pt]
m\mid A-a,\ B-b&\,\Rightarrow\, m\mid AB-ab\qquad\text{Divisibility Product Rule}\\[4pt] 
{\bf Proof}\quad (A-a)B+a(B&-b)\, = AB-ab\end{align}$$

Thus the inductive step need not be pulled out of a hat like magic. Rather, it has  intuitive arithmetical content as congruence multiplication. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1275622/242) for further discussion.

Note: I wrote the congruence proof in the above form (vs. simpler congruence forms) in order to better highlight how other answers are *precisely* equivalent to applying the Product Rule.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$2^{(n+1)+2}+3^{2(n+1)+1}=2(2^{n+2})+(7+2)3^{2n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(n)=2^{n+2}+3^{2n+1}$$ so that $$f(n+1)=2^{n+3}+3^{2n+3}$$

Then

$$ \begin{align} f(n+1)-f(n) &= 2^{n+3}+3^{2n+3}-2^{n+2}-3^{2n+1} \\
&= 2^{n+2} \left(2-1 \right)+3^{2n+1}\left(3^2 - 1 \right) \\
&= 2^{n+2} + 8\left(3^{2n+1}\right) \\
&= 2^{n+2} + 3^{2n+1} + 7\left(3^{2n+1}\right) \end{align} $$

We assumed that $2^{n+2} + 3^{2n+1} ~|~ 7$ and $7\left(3^{2n+1}\right)$ is obviously divisble by 7. So we're done.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\geq 1$, you are trying to show that $2^{n+2}+3^{2n+1}=7m$, where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. You already did the base case.

Fix some $k\geq 1$, and assume that 
$$
2^{k+2}+3^{2k+1}=7\ell, \ell\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
To be shown is that
$$
2^{k+3}+3^{2k+3}=7\eta, \eta\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$
Start with the left-hand side and work your way to the right hand side, completing the inductive step:
\begin{align}
2^{k+3}+3^{2k+3} &= 2\cdot 2^{k+2}+9\cdot 3^{2k+1}\\[0.5em]
&= 9(2^{k+2}+3^{2k+1})-7\cdot 2^{k+2}\\[0.5em]
&= 9(7\ell)-7\cdot 2^{k+2}\\[0.5em]
&= 7(9\ell-2^{k+2})\\[0.5em]
&= 7\eta.
\end{align}
This concludes the proof. I might write it up slightly more formally, but those are the key steps.