# Reference request - ideals and normal subgroups in category theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory

I'm looking for a categorial notion of a normal subgroup and an ideal (of a ring, and a non-associative algebra).

Basing on the following observations:

- they are used to define quotient objects in the category of groups and commutative rings,
- given a connected Lie group, there is a correspondence between its normal connected Lie subgroups and ideals of its Lie algebra,

I expect that there may exist a construction in category theory generalizing these notions.

Comment: Yes, $A\hookrightarrow B$ is (isomorphic to) an embedding of an ideal of $B$ iff it is a *kernel* of some $g:B\to C$ (that is, the equalizer of $g$ and the trivial morphism).

Comment: You may find of interest [my post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42125/242) on ideal-determined varieties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the notion of a [congruence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/congruence). It's a convenient fact about groups resp. rings that congruences are equivalent to normal subgroups resp. (two-sided) ideals; in general, for example when dealing with monoids, you really need to work with congruences.