# Struggling to understand principal ideals in Ring Theory

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

I studied group theory last year and the concept of $<g>$ or $<g,h>$ for elements $g,h$ of a group $G$ made complete sense as it was just the set of all the products of elements within $< >$ and their inverses just like how span works.
Now when I get to Ring Theory (old edition with NO UNITAL ELEMENT requirement) the definition of $<r>$ and $<r,s>$ for $r,s$ in a ring $R$ just doesn’t make sense anymore as it’s no longer just the products (and addition) of the elements within $< >$ but instead involves elements outside of $< >$ as well.

I just can’t picture in my head what’s going on here and it’s making harder following my classes harder. For example one line in a proof we were doing was:

“Clearly $<a>^3 \subseteq RaR$“ ($R$ is a ring and $a$ is an element in $R$) but this isn’t at all clear for me.

Comment: No, it doesn't involve elements outside of $\langle\rangle$. The ideal in $R$ generated by $a$ is often denoted by $(a)$. What is $\langle a\rangle$ for you?

Comment: @DietrichBurde What do you mean? Yes it does of course, $2X\in<2>\subset \Bbb Z[X]$ but $X$ is not in the $<>$ here.

Comment: Of course $X\in \langle 2\rangle =2\Bbb R[X]$ is in there. This means, it is an element of it.

Comment: It's in there, but it's not specifically inside the brackets. Well, maybe this is more clear with $\Bbb Z$, edited.

Comment: I don't think that this is what the OP meant, because then for groups $\langle g\rangle $ also has not $g^2$ in there.

Comment: @DietrichBurde But you get $g^2$ just by multiplying $g$ by $g$, and both $g$ and $g$ are in there.

Comment: Not with $g^{-1}$, though. That's not necessarily from $g\cdot g\cdots$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Are you trolling here? Of course $g^{-1}$ comes from inverting $g$. Inverting and multiplying are your two natural things to do in a group.

Comment: I’m confused it is defined to include the products of elements in $<>$ with those outside $<>$

Comment: But $g^{-1}$ is not written in $(g)$ in the same way, as $X$ is not written in $(2)=2\Bbb Z[X]$.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are specifying that your ring doesn't have a unit, you need to be careful when defining ideals: $\left<a\right>$ is not the set of all multiples of $a$, since otherwise $a$ would not necessarily be an element of $\left<a\right>$ as there is no unit.

$\left<a\right>$ is the smallest subset of $R$ that

- contains $a$
- is an additive subgroup
- is stable by external multiplication with elements of $R$.

This last requirement, which is the one that bothers you, is actually quite natural. You can think of how an even number is still an even number when you multiply it by *any* number, odd or even (here we are looking at the set of even numbers, $\left<2\right>$, inside $\Bbb Z$).

See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42085/why-are-ideals-more-important-than-subrings) regarding why ideals play a more important role than subrings in ring theory.

Comment: What is $I$ ??.

Comment: @Anteater23 Sorry $R$. Edited.

Comment: So we’re defining it is a completely different way to group theory so that <a> is the smallest ideal containing $a$?

Comment: @Anteater23 Absolutely.

Comment: Why do we want it defined this way though? What’s wrong with <a> being the smallest SUBRING of R containing a? Note: by my book every ideal is a subring so ideal is a stronger condition.

Comment: How does the definition guarantee that $a$ lies in <a>. I can’t see this.

Comment: @Anteater23 I've added a link that answers that.

Comment: How do we know a lies in <a>?

Comment: @Anteater23 By the very definition of $<a>$, it's requirement #1.

Comment: Ok. So there’s no actual definition which describes the elements in <a>?

Comment: There is the other answer by rogerl which is valid when $R$ has a unit: in this case $\left<a\right>$ is the set of all multiples of $a$ by an element of $R$. Otherwise, you're right, there is no such description.

Comment: So <a> is {a union ra union ar for all r in R}

Comment: @Anteater23 No, because $a+ra$ is not a multiple of $a$ either.

Comment: Yes but if a is in <a> and ra is in <a> then a+ra in is <a> as it is additive subgroup no?

Comment: @Anteater23 Yes, which is why your description {a union ra union ar for all r in R} is wrong. It's more complicated and I don't believe there is a closed description of all elements.

Comment: So <a> ={a+ra+ar} for all r in R :) ?

Comment: @Anteater23 Try to prove it, if it's true then the proof will be straightforward, and if not you will see why.