# Are all congruence relations on $(\mathbb{Z},+)$ of the form mod n for some integer n?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Congruence mod n is a congruence relation for integer addition. Is the converse true? That is, is every congruence relation for integer addition of the form mod n for some integer n?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by congruence relation? One well defined under the addition of $mathbb Z$?

Comment: @paulblartmathcop An equivalence relation R such that aRb and cRd implies a+cRb+d

Comment: Generally for any commutative ring $R$, a quotient by a congruence corresponds to the quotient ring by the ideal of all elements $\equiv 0$. Further a congruence is the same as a sub-$R$-algebra of the square $R^2$. This is explained at length in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16157/242) in the linked dupe.

Comment: The algebraic structures (likes rings and groups) whose congruences are determined by by a single congruence class are known as [ideal determined varieties.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42125/242)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the trivial relation, $a\sim b\iff a=b$ is a congruence relation in this sense.

Let's assume that there is some pair, $a>b $, with $a\sim b$.    Then $(a-b)\sim 0$ so there is  some positive integer $n$ such that $n \sim 0$.  Let $n$ be the least positive integer with $n\sim 0$.

We then contend that $a\sim b \iff n\,|\,(a-b)$.

Note first that $\Leftarrow$ is clear.

Now suppose $a\sim b$ with $a>b$.  We write $(a-b)=nq+r$ where $0≤r<n$.  It is easy to see that $r\sim 0$ so if $r\neq 0$ we'd contradict the minimality of $n$ and we are done.