# What is the difference between ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and congruence to modulo $n$.

Tags: ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is the difference between ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and congruence to modulo $n$.

Are they same thing or what are significant differences between them except we can use integers greater than $n$ for modulo operations. They look like the same.

Comment: Congruence modulo $n$ is a _relation_, so it cannot be a _ring_. They are entirely different types of things; this alone should suffice as an answer.

Comment: @Marc That's not true generally - see my comment to your answer.

Comment: @BillDubuque: just for clarity: by "That" you apparently mean "Congruence is a relation". You claim congruence _can_ be defined as a subalgebra (of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ in this case). That's fine with me, although it's not likely that OP considers it this way. And even then, this subalgebra is rather different from $\Bbb Z_n$.

Comment: @Marc You stated that "a congruence cannot be a *ring*". That is false. In fact that a ring congruence *is a ring* is an *essential* property of a congruence. One cannot argue such semantic points so simply.

Comment: @BillDubuque: As I said, it's fine with me; have a nice day. But I actually meant to say a relation cannot be a ring; maybe that is not even quite true set-theoretically, but I don't care.

Answer (score 2):

First, review the definition of what a ring is.

In particular, it's a type of algebraic structure with two different binary operations defined on it (sometimes referred to as "addition" and "multiplication").

Next, review the definition of the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and you will see that the two binary operations on it are just addition mod $n$ and multiplication mod $n$.

These are interrelated concepts, but the former is a type of algebraic structure with operations, and the latter ($+$ mod $n$ and $\times$ mod $n$) are examples of operations; so they are certainly not one and the same.

Answer (score 1):

They are of one, but they are different kinds of mathematical objects.

Congruence modulo $n$ is an *equivalence relation* on $\Bbb Z$, whereas $\Bbb Z_n$ is a *ring*, namely the quotient ring by the congruence modulo $n$ relation (meaning that two elements of $\Bbb Z$ are regarded *identical* in $\Bbb Z_n$ iff they are congruent mod $n$).

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment, something positive can be said about the relation between the congrence modulo $n$ and the ring  $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$: the latter is the *quotient* of the the ring $\Bbb n$ by the relation of congrence modulo $n$.

This means the elements of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ are *classes* of the relation of congrence modulo $n$ (which is an equivalence relation; any equivalence relation gives a *partition* of the set it is defined on into *equivalence classes*). Moreover the operations of addition and multiplication in $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ are derived from those operations in $\Bbb Z$: to perform one of these operations, one chooses elements (representatives) from the classes to be added/multiplied, one performs the corresponding operation upon them in $\Bbb Z$, and finally one takes the class (modulo $n$) of the resulting number.

It is a non-trivial fact, which can be proved, that every set of choices of representatives will give the same end result (a class modulo $n$); this is why the quotient ring of $\Bbb Z$ by the relation of equivalence modulo $n$ is defined in the first place. (And it explains why there is no such thing as a quotient *ring* $\Bbb R/n\Bbb R$; in this case the required property for defining multiplication fails.)

Comment: Generally it is not true that congruences are defined to be merely a *set*-theoretic object such as an equivalence relation. That fails to capture the *algebraic* essence of a congruence. Instead, congruences are more naturally defined *algebraically:* a congruence of a general algebraic structure $\,\rm A\,$ is a certain sub-*algebra* of $\rm\,A^2$ (containing the diagonal $\rm\,A(1,1),\:$ etc). For example, see my [answer here,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/16157/242) which discusses in detail ring congruences on $\,\Bbb Z\,$ from this viewpoint.

Comment: @BillDubuque: Doubtless you are right (although I think what you say is essentially the same as saying an equivalence relation that is also compatible with the algebraic operations so that these can be transferred to the quotient; this is just what I said, differently), but I doubt whether OP has the mathematical maturity to understand your answer. Or indeed mine.