# Find a subring of $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$ that is not an ideal of $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find a subring of $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$ that is not an ideal of $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$.

I can't see any way a subring of $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$ can NOT be an ideal.  Subrings of $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$ are of the form $n\Bbb Z \oplus k\Bbb Z$ where $n$ and $k$ are integers.  So for something to not be an ideal in $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$ there must be an $x = (j_1, j_2)$ in $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$ and an $y = (b_1n, b_2k)$ in $n\Bbb Z \oplus k\Bbb Z$ such that $xy$ or $yx \notin$ $n\Bbb Z \oplus k\Bbb Z$.  But this doesn't make sense because it seems any integer pair can be reached.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The subring $R = \{(m,m)\mid m \in \Bbb Z\}$ is not an ideal. This is easily checked since $(1,1)\in R$ but $(0,1)\cdot (1,1) = (0,1) \notin R$.

Comment: It seems that R={(m,m) : m $\in Z^{+}$} would have worked equally well.

Comment: This also disproves the OP's assertion that all subrings are of the form $n\mathbb Z\oplus k\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot leave comments unfortunately, so I am responding in this answer to [@Mathematicing's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920409/find-a-subring-of-bbb-z-oplus-bbb-z-that-is-not-an-ideal-of-bbb-z-oplus/4609292#comment4709303_1920412) that "$R=\{(m,m) : m \in\Bbb Z^+\}$ would have worked equally well.". In fact, this is not a subring because it is not closed under subtraction: consider $(1, 1) - (2, 2) = (-1, -1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Any subring would I presume contain $(1,1)$, the ring's unity (this is not the only possible interpretation).

Then any proper subring will do.

The proper subrings are the $R_n=\{(a,b)\in\Bbb Z^2\mid a\equiv b\pmod n\},$ for $n\gt1.$  See @Qiaochu's proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16128/1070376).

$R_\infty$ is @Arthur's example.