# Prove the converse to Euclid's lemma [e.g. for polynomials]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $k$ be a field and let $f(x)$ be a nonconstant polynomial. If, whenever $f$ divides a product of two polynomials, it necessarily divides one of the factors, then $f$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose if $f$ divides a product it divides some factor, and suppose $\,f\,$ splits $\,f=gh\,$. Then

$f = gh\mid gh\,\Rightarrow\, gh\mid g\ $ or $\ gh\mid h\,\Rightarrow\, h\mid 1\ $ or $\ g\mid 1,\,$ so $f$ is irreducible (so prime in a UFD)

**Remark** $ $ Generally, as above, if $\, f\mid gh,\ f\nmid g,\ f\nmid h\,$ then $\,\gcd(f,g)\,$ is a *proper* factor of $\,f,\,$ i.e. if we have specific witnesses $\,g,h\,$ to nonprimality of $\,f\,$  then we can use them split $\,f\,$ into proper factors using an efficient gcd algorithm. In other words, there is a *constructive* proof of the contrapositive of prime $\,\Rightarrow\,$ irreducible in Euclidean (gcd) domains (the converse of the OP). See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1129120/242) for further discussion.

Comment: This helped a lot.  Thank you so much

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3501097/242) for a **co**prime generalization.