# For integral domain $R$, show that $a \mid c, b \mid c \implies ab \mid c$ when $(a, b)$ unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This kind of question has been asked before, but for a UFD.  I want to show the result, more generally, for an integral domain.

Let $R$ be an integral domain (not necessarily a UFD).

Suppose $a, b \in R$ with $d \mid  a,\;d \mid  b \implies d$ unit.

Show that

$a  \mid  c,\; b  \mid   c \implies ab \mid  c$

EDIT: Or find a counterexample.  Turns out the result is not true, in general!

Comment: Hint: show that the assumption on $a$ and $b$ implies that the ideal $\langle a,b\rangle$ is all of $R$, so that you can write $1=ar+bs$ for some $r,s\in R$.

Comment: @GregMartin: This is false in general. Counterexample: in $K[X,Y]$ ($K$ being a field), the indeterminates have no common divisor, yet they generate a maximal ideal.

Comment: What do you denote $(a,b)$ exactly, in this context?

Comment: @Bernard $(a, b)$ denotes (i) $d \mid a, d \mid b$ and (ii) $d' \mid a, d' \mid b \implies d' \mid d$

Comment: So you do not have general integral  domain, but a *gcd domain*?

Comment: @Bernard I was thinking for when there are such $a$ and $b$, not any gcd, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Bernard $(a,b)$ unit can be interpreted to mean they are coprime, i.e. have only unit common divisors, so the question makes sense as stated, i.e. the domain need not be a gcd domain.

Comment: @BillDubuque I think it is a very ambiguous notation, as it implicitly lets the reader there's a Bézout's relation between $a$ and $b$

Comment: @Bernard Only if you insist on reading $\,(a,b)\,$ as an ideal vs. gcd. But it is quite common notation for gcds also, esp, when studing divisibility theory. Usually any ambiguity is easily resolved from the context (and sometimes it is *inbtended* when a result holds for both ideals and gcds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true in all domains since it implies atoms (irreducibles) $\,p\,$ are prime, i.e.

$$p\mid ab,\ p\nmid a\,\Rightarrow\, (a,p)=1,\ \ {\rm so}\,\ \  a,p\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, ap\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid b$$

So any non-UFD number ring yields a counterexample, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37089/242) for that and more.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general. The ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not an UFD, and for example you have two factorizations of $21=3\times 7=(4+\sqrt{-5})\times(4-\sqrt{-5})$. Now put $a=3$, $b=4+\sqrt{-5}$ and $c=21$.

Comment: Thanks Stinking Bishop and @Bill Dubuque.  Now I know why I couldn't prove it!  I wanted to use this result for proving that in an integral domain $R$, every nonempty set of nonzero elements of $R$ has a highest common factor if and only if every nonempty set of nonzero elements of $R$ has a least common multiple.

Comment: @Oscar If you say more about your context I may be able to be more specific. I discuss related results in many answers, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/611202/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3057093/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3501097/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14122/242). Note: you can't ping people under answers they weren't commenting in (so the above didn't work)

Comment: @BillDubuque Basically, I'm working through the exercises in the Galois theory textbook by Garling, and a particular exercise asks to show that in an integral domain $R$, every nonempty set of nonzero elements of $R$ has a highest common factor if and only if every nonempty set of nonzero elements of $R$ has a least common multiple. From the discussion here, I realize it is asking to show GCD domain $\iff$ LCM domain, and so I'm interested in a GCD domain after all, for the question I've asked. Then I found this link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449521/gcd-domain-is-lcm-domain

Comment: @Oscar The results in Khurana's expository paper are very old and well-known, e.g. see Section 1.6, Factorization in Commutative Monoids,
in Robert Gilmer's book: *Commutative Semigroup Rings*, 1984.

Comment: @Oscar But Gilmer's book was not online, so I often mentioned Khurana's paper instead, e.g way back in 2012 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/131871/242), and earlier on sci.math. Nice to see that Xam and others have added expositions here (strangely no one ever sparked me to yet - it's more general than most questions here).

Comment: @Oscar An excellent place to start learning more about this and closely related topics is the survey article by D. D. Anderson "GCD domains..." that I cite [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/121699/242)