# If $f(x)$ is irreducible then content of $f(x)=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $R$ be a UFD and $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n \in R[x]$. Then the
> content of $f(x)$, denoted by $C(f)=gcd(a_0,a_1,...,a_n)$.

Let $R$ be a UFD and $f(x) \in R[x]$ is a non-constant irreducible polynomial in $R[x]$.Then is it must that $C(f)=1$?

I am asking this because if I take $f(x)=4x^3+2x^2+2x+2 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Then $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but it's $C(f)=2$

Comment: Doesn't $2\mid f$ ? More generally, doesn't $C(f)\mid f$?

Comment: But $f(x)$ is reducible if it is product of non constant polynomials, here 2 is constant

Comment: Read again the definitions. An element $x$ of a domain is irreducible if and only if it isn't $0$ or invertible and, for all $a,b$ such that $x=ab$, $a$ is invertible or $b$ is invertible.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio yeah I know that definition,  according to that definition f(x) is not irreducible  as 2 is not unit.

Comment: I have read that definition in case of an element of $R$ that an element $q \in R$ is said to be irreducible  in $R$ iff $q$ is non zero non unit and whenever $q=bc $ for $b,c \in R$ then $b$ or $c$ is a unit.

Comment: @AlvinL The definition of reducible be as it may, the exercise asks for an irreducible polynomial, not for a polynomial that isn't reducible.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio But I am also confusing with that  definition of irreduciblity of polynomials, that says $f(x) \in R[x]$ is irreducible if there doesn't exist $u(x),v(x)$ in $R[x]$ suchthat $f(x)=u(x)v(x)$ where $0 \lt deg u \lt deg f$ and $0 \lt deg v \lt deg f$

Comment: @Epsilon101 I have stated what I claim is the standard definition of irreducible polynomial in a domain, and uner that definition the theorem holds. You claim it's a different one, and under that definition the claim is false. I see no point in further discussion.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio is there a difference between not reducible and irreducible?

Comment: With my definitions, no. With yours, no. With a mix of the two, yes, for the reason we've discussed.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio My mistake, got hung up on semantics.

Comment: @AlvinL I don't know if you did, but I certainly did.

Comment: You seem to be attempting to use a definition of "irreducible" polynomial  that works only for polynomials over a *field* - see the linked dupe. This is a common oversight.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2983648/242) on definition(s) of "irreducible" in integral domains.