# Are there always prime elements in a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am reading a proof which uses the fact that every PID has a prime element (it takes a prime element from a PID), and I am thinking whether every PID has a prime element.

If the PID is not a field, I believe there is an irreducible element which is a prime. If it is a field, $0$ is a prime element since $(0)$ is a prime ideal, but it's not an irreducible element. However, we claim that irreducible elements and prime elements in a PID are the same. Is $0$ in a field a prime element? How can we assume that every PID has a prime?

Comment: I don't think fields have prime elements. They don't need any for the purposes of divisibility studies because every non-zero element is a unit. Yes, fields are PIDs. Exactly how is the text you are studying using the primeness? Would the result be trivial for fields?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The text is Lang's $\textit{algebra}$ and when proving the fact that every free module over a PID has a dimension, he writes something like "take a prime element from the PID...." Lang doesn't exclude the possibility that the PID might be a field.

Comment: Ok. As I suspected, there is no need to cater for the case of a field. Vector spaces have a dimension. Actually, that particular claim is often proven by reducing it to the case of a field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you. Do you mean that I can assume the PID is not a field? Is it that every PID which is not a field has an irreducible element, and thus a prime element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct statement is that every PID *which is not a field* has a prime element.

Hint: use the fact that every nonzero ring has at least one maximal ideal.

Comment: And every maximal ideal is a prime ideal in a PID, which indicates that a PID has a prime element. Thank you for your answer! I think my confusion is more of: $0$ should be a prime element by the definition but then irreducible elements are actually not the same as prime elements?

Comment: @Coco the definition of prime element should exclude $0$. i.e. a prime element should be "a nonzero element $p$ such that $p|ab$ implies $p|a$ or $p|b$". Then primes and irreducibles are the same in a PID (but not in general)

Comment: Thank you. But this way, not every PID (such as a field) has a prime element, but the author writes "take a prime element from a PID.." @AlexMathers

Comment: @Coco It is likely that if the PID is a field then the result is trivial, and the author forgot to write this. You ought to separate into two cases for yourself in a more careful way than the author is doing: case 1) the PID is a field, and case 2) the PID is not a field. In the latter case you can apply the argument you see in the book, and in case 1) the result is likely simple

Comment: @Coco Alex forgot the "nonunit" hypothesis in the definition of a prime element. [Primes are irreducible (atoms)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2983648/242) but the converse (AP := atoms are prime) is not generally true (it is equivalent to *uniqueness* of factorizations into atoms, which does hold true in gcd domains (e.g. UFDs and PIDs). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2983648/242) for many other closely related divisibility properties.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks for catching that, my mistake

Comment: @AlexMathers Gosh you remind me that if the ring is a field, then a module (whether free or not) is a vector space, then the dimension is well-defined. Thank you!