# First Isomorphism Theorem in Generality

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quotient objects, their universal property and the isomorphism theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61062/quotient-objects-their-universal-property-and-the-isomorphism-theorems)

In how general of a setting is the first isomorphism theorem true? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem) states it in terms of universal algebra, but is there some category theoretic version of the theorem as well (in particular, is there a suitable notion of a quotient)?

Comment: Closely related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/61062/