# Clarification on quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've only recently started looking at quotient groups, so I don't know if this question will make sense...

In [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset), $G/H$ is defined as the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$, without any reference to whether or not $H$ is normal. In the [quotient group article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group), however, the definition of is stated only for when $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

1. What accounts for the discrepancy between the two articles?
2. Are quotient groups only defined when $H \triangleleft G$?
3. If one is trying to determine what $G/H$ is explicitly, will this be affected  if $H$ is normal or not? Are there any caveats I should anticipate if $H$ is *not* normal?

I do want to note that I came across a [similar](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14282/why-do-we-define-quotient-groups-for-normal-subgroups-only) article, but I don't understand it all.

Comment: $G/H$ is a set in general. If $H$ is normal, it's also a group.

Comment: You might enjoy [this blog post by Gowers](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/11/20/normal-subgroups-and-quotient-groups/).

Comment: To add to Qiaochu's comment, $G/H$ is also always a $G$-space.

Comment: what part about the other post do you not understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$G/H\,$ is **quotient group** if and only if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.  However, the **notation** $G/H$ denotes the **set of left cosets** of $H$ in $G$, and it does not necessarily denote a **quotient group**.  If it  also happens to be the case that $\;H \triangleleft G,\;$ then $G/H$ is not just the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$, but *also* a **group**, namely, the *quotient group*, sometimes referred to as the *factor group*, the group of cosets under "coset multiplication", which of course is defined if and only if the left cosets of $H$ equal the right cosets of $H$ in $G$: i.e., if and only if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I gave the OP a TU, you too! :-)

Comment: Love it+++++++++

Comment: quotient group has puzzled me for along time when i saw it first time , it was hard to my mind to deal with sets as elements , it still puzzles me from time to time but less than the past.

Answer (score 1):

G/H is the set of all left cosets of H in G but this is only a group if H is a normal subgroup. It is then a quotient group.

Comment: Oops you're right I got the slash wrong