# Abelian Quotient group, which is not normal

Tags: group-theory

What would be an example of a group $G$ with subgroup $H$ such that $G/H$ is abelian but $H$ is not normal?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14282/why-do-we-define-quotient-groups-for-normal-subgroups-only/

Answer (score 4):

You can only make quotient groups with normal subgroups. Otherwise it is not well-defined.

So it is in fact impossible to give an example of this :)

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group for details.

Comment: It's impossible even if OP replaces "is abelian" with "exists".