# An example to prove that all cosets do not form a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I read that only cosets (G/H) such that H is a normal subgroup form a factor group. Can anyone tell me an example of a case where cosets do not form a group ?

Comment: Related (but not actually a duplicate since this question is about an example) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14282/why-do-we-define-quotient-groups-for-normal-subgroups-only/

Answer (score 4):

Take any group $G$ with a non-normal subgroup.  For example $G = S_{3}$ and $H = \langle (1 \ 2) \rangle$.  The cosets are 
$$\{e, (1 \ 2)\}, \ \{e, (1 \ 2)\} \cdot (1 \ 3) = \{(1 \ 3),(1 \ 3 \ 2)\},\ \{e, (1 \ 2)\} \cdot (2 \ 3) = \{(2 \ 3), (1 \ 2 \ 3)\}.$$
Multiplication between cosets is not well defined, because for example 
$$e \cdot (1 \ 3) =(1 \ 3) \in \{(1 \ 3), (1 \ 3 \ 2)\}$$ 
but 
$$(1 \ 2) \cdot (1\ 3\ 2) = (1 \ 2\ 3) \in \{(2 \ 3), (1 \ 2 \ 3)\}.$$

Comment: Can this be adapted to show that no multiplication can be defined, so that we may be sure the cosets don't form any group? EDIT: answer is clearly no, just set-biject the elements with a cyclic group.

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers can you explain your answer a bit more the part towards the end where you say that multiplication is not well defined.tx in advance.