# Is G/H a group even if H is a subgroup of G but not a normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

I know we can have left and right cosets without having the group be normal, but can we mod out by a subgroup without it being normal and still get a group?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No. A subgroup is normal if and only if the quotient is a group. The quotient still makes sense when the subgroup is not normal, but it has no operation. That is indeed the purpose of singling out normal subgroups.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me an example, I'm having a hard time thinking of one

Comment: Take $S_3$ and the subgroup of order $2$ generated by $(12)$.

Comment: Search the site for the dupe answer.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14282/why-do-we-define-quotient-groups-for-normal-subgroups-only/