# Proving conditions for normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I was watching the following online lecture on normal subgroups, and came across the following proof:
[Normal and quotient groups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYKdh5oQ4Zw&list=PLi01XoE8jYoi3SgnnGorR_XOW3IcK-TP6&index=8)

If we have some group, G, and some subgroup of G, let's say N, we can construct left cosets like so:

Each left coset: $gN$ for some $g \in G$.

Now we pick two cosets: $xN, yN$. Now since $e \in N$,

$x.e = x \in xN$ and $y.e = y \in yN$.

**Now here is the part that I don't understand:**

For cosets to act like a group:

$x.y \in (xN)(yN)$

Why must this be true? And what is $(xN)(yN)$.Is it the element-wise group operation of each element in $xN$ and $yN$?

Then the proof said:
$i.e. (xN)(yN) = xyN$.

This does not make sense to me, what is so obvious about this statement?

Comment: If you want to be able to multiply cosets as if they were a group, you need (i) the element-wise product of two cosets to be a coset; and (ii) since $xy$ lies in the element-wise product of $xN$ and $yN$, you need the coset that results from doing $(xN)(yN)$ to be the coset $xyN$. This holds for normal subgroups [and only for normal subgroups](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14315/742). By the way: it is impossible to help you understand their justificaiton unless we know what lecture you are talking about. There are multiple ways to establish these things. By not saying, you prevent help.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I added the lecture, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Could you also explain why $(xN)(yN) \in xyN$?

Comment: It is not true that $(xN)(yN)\in xyN$; the left side is a set, not an element. For normal subgroups, $gN=Ng$ for all $g\in G$. So $(xN)(yN) = x(Ny)N = x(yN)N = xyNN = xyN$, because for any subgroup $H$, $HH=H$. This is all done in the post I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $$xy\in(xN)(yN)\tag{1}$$ is not necessary for the set of cosets to be a group.  Instead, (1) is the condition for multiplication on cosets to be *deducible* from multiplication in your original group.

(In fact, if there are $n$ cosets, then we can always make them a group by choosing an arbitrary bijection to the cyclic group on $n$ elements.  But this usually isn't a very interesting group structure, because it is entirely unrelated to the original $G$ we started out with.)

Recall that each coset is the equivalence class of elements of $g$ that differ by an element of $N$; that is, $$xN=\{nx:n\in N\}$$  This set has a *representation* as $xN$, but this representation is not unique: if $n\in N$, then $(xn)N=xN$.  (For example, consider $D_3/C_2$.  This means: take the group of symmetries of a triangle; any reflection $r$ generates a (non-normal) subgroup.  That subgroup has three cosets, which I will call $C_2$, $\rho C_2$, and $\rho^2C_2$.  You can verify that $rC_2=C_2$, $\rho rC_2=\rho C_2$, etc.)

We want a multiplication on cosets that arises from multiplication in $G$, so that we can deduce $(xN)(yN)$ just by computing $(xy)N$.  But we have no guarantee that the coset $(xy)N$ doesn't depend on *which* $x$ and $y$ we choose to represent $xN$ and $yN$.

One way to fix this is to say: given two cosets $K_1$ and $K_2$, the natural multiplication is $$K_1K_2=\{k_1k_2:k_1\in K_1, k_2\in K_2\}$$  This allows us to define $(xN)(yN)$, and one can check that the result is a coset precisely when $N$ is normal.  We want this multiplication to line up with multiplication in $G$: $$(xN)(yN)=xyN$$  To ensure this, we follow Arturo Magidin's comment: if $xy\in(xN)(yN)$, then $$xyN\subseteq(xN)(yN)N=(xN)(yN)$$  Since both sides are cosets, they cannot contain each other strictly.  Thus $xyN=(xN)(yN)$, as desired.